# from google import google ImportError: cannot import name 'google' from 'google' (unknown location)

Tags: python, google-api

from google import google
I install google package but it's still giving me following error.

from google import google
ImportError: cannot import name 'google' from 'google' (unknown location)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem and what you did try before posting. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The google package I use does not have a submodule named 'google'.

Mine looks like this when using vscode:

[image]

It depends on which google package you're using though, looks like there is an official one then another one on pypi